# how to migrate the hidden files using rsync

Tags: command-line, bash, rsync, hidden-files

I am using the command below, in my target sever:

```
rsync -ab myuser@sourcehost:/source_dir/* target_dir
```

But this is not able to sync the hidden files present source_dir
anything I need to use any `--include` so that the hidden files can be migrated.

But that include option should not affect the migration of normal files as I'm using this command in my script.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not `rsync`, but the shell.

Normally in Ubuntu, `dotglob` is disabled, meaning that files starting with `.` are excluded from `*` expansion.

You can turn this on running.

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Then your command should work (I think you're just missing `-e ssh`)

It's sensible to unset `dotglob` after use with:

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

---

Alternatively, you can simply tell `rsync` to copy the folder contents to `target_dir`, which includes hidden files:

```
rsync --ab -e ssh myuser@sourcehost:/source_dir/ target_dir
```

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/691980/how-to-customize-the-bash-shell-with-shopt/